# Object values doesn't match table columns in Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

**The attributes of my PersonalInfo object doesn't match the database columns while inserting a new record.**

I've tried some methods to do this and I hadn't had any problem so far.

I've tried the following

- 1.-  `session.save(Object)`
- 2.-  `session.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery)`

  Both of them work fine, the only drawback with the last one is that the table has 8 fields, this means I have to write too much code setting each parameter into the Query object.

  Now I'm trying to use the `@SQLInsert` annotation, then I got the problem I mentioned previously. 
  I really don't know what's going on, it makes me think that maybe a single config parameter is missing or something like that.

**I've already checked I'm passing the information in the right order by getting this output from the console.**

```
PersonalInfo [userId=30, password=myPass, status=0, type=student, firstName=Francisco, lastName=Hernandez, secondLastName=Salgado, sessionId=]

Hibernate: INSERT INTO personal_info (userId, password, status, type, firstName, lastName, secondLastName, sessionId) VALUES(?, MD5(?) , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**This is a snippet of code from  my PersonalInfo class which demonstrates the use of annotations**.

```
@Entity(name="personal_info")
@SQLInsert(sql="INSERT INTO personal_info (userId, password, status, type, firstName, lastName, secondLastName, sessionId)"
                + " VALUES(?, MD5(?) , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")

public class PersonalInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name ="lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name ="secondLastName")
    private String secondLastName;

    @Column(name ="sessionId")
    private String sessionId;

}
```

**The method to perform the insert operation.**

```
public int save(PersonalInfo personalInfo){                             
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();             
         session.beginTransaction();            
             int result = (Integer)session.save(personalInfo);      
         session.getTransaction().commit();     
    session.close();                        
    return result;
}
```

**And finally the main method.**

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    // I've ommited some attributes that have a default value so they're initialized within the constructor
    PersonalInfo personalInfo= new PersonalInfoBuilder("Francisco","Hernandez","Salgado")
                    .withLogInInfo(30, "myPass")
                    .withType("student").build();

    System.out.println(personalInfo);

    new PersonalInfoDAO(sessionFactory).save(personalInfo);             

}
```

**As well as the output I get from postgresql after inserting.**

[image]

**As averybody can see the values doesn't match the columns.
Sorry for the table column names, I decided make a translation from Spanish to English so that more people will be able to help me**

```
PersonalInfo [userId=30, password=myPass, status=0, type=student, firstName=Francisco, lastName=Hernandez, secondLastName=Salgado, sessionId=]
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the md5 from the insert query?

Comment: I've done that but I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The line below saves datosPersonales and not personalInfo from the main method.

new PersonalInfoDAO(sessionFactory).save(datosPersonales);

personalInfo has the correct information and datosPersonales does not.

Comment: It's a type mistake, datosPersonales it's actually personalInfo